# Extract a number in a txt file by using regular expressions

Tags: command-line, bash, python, text-processing

I am saving the output of terminal by `2>&1 | tee ./
results.txt` in a `.txt` file which has the following text:

```
executing: ./home/images/image-001-041.png
0,33, /results/image-001-041.png
1.7828,32, /results/image-001-040.png
1.86051,34, /results/image-001-042.png
1.90462,31, /results/image-001-039.png
1.90954,30, /results/image-001-038.png
1.91953,35, /results/image-001-043.png
1.92677,28, /results/image-001-036.png
1.92723,3160, /results/image-037-035.png
1.93353,7450, /results/image-086-035.png
1.93375,1600, /results/image-019-044.png
```

I need to take the second numbers (after first comma sign, i.e. 33,32,34,...) and save it in a list in `Python`. What is the bash command, or the regular expression command in python?
Thanks

Comment: `awk -F ',' '{print $2}' results.txt`

Comment: @EliahKagan I had intended to put an answer but got interrupted. By the time I posted, there were already a couple answers there so I decided to leave it as a helpful comment. I appreciate the insight and nudge.

Comment: @stumblebee Who said having couple answers is an issue ? Ask Ubuntu isn't a race, it's a marathon and all about *usefulness* of answers.  I see you posted one already. Good job !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -sd',' -f2 < result.txt
```

from [`man cut`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cut.1.html):

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
-s, --only-delimited
          do not print lines not containing delimiters
-f, --fields=LIST
          select only these fields;  also print any line that contains
          no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use awk

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' results.txt
```

Define a comma as the field separator and print the second column.

Answer (score 5):

Example with `sed`

```
$ sed -rn 's/[^,]+,([^,]+),.*/\1/p' results.txt
33
32
34
31
30
35
28
3160
7450
1600
```

#### Notes

- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it (removes non-matching lines)
- `-r` use ERE (so we don't need backslashes for `+` and `(` `)` metacharacters)
- `[^,]+,` some non-commas followed by a comma
- `([^,]+),` save some non-commas followed by a comma for later (we only want this part)
- `.*` any number of any characters (gets rid of the rest of the line)
- `\1` the pattern we saved
- `p` print the lines we changed (needed with `-n`)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention Python:

```
with open('results.txt') as results:
    ids = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in results if ',' in line]
    print(ids)
```

It creates a list of integers as `ids`, and displays it:

```
[33, 32, 34, 31, 30, 35, 28, 3160, 7450, 1600]
```

Comment: One may also turn the output into a string to print on stdout for further processing, since having list (with brackets and commas) can be undesirable. Use `"\n".join(ids)` for printing each item on separate line or `" ".join(ids)` for space-separated list.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: OP specifically mentioned that the ids should be saved as a list in python. That's what the above code does. Once its in a list, in can be processed as you wish.

Comment: Ah, missed that part. Typically these types of questions ask to just extract the data and that's it.   Don't worry, you've got a good answer there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perl which is similar to the awk and sed solutions posted.

`-a` enables automatic splitting on each line.

`-F` is used to specify the delimiter to split each line. It defaults to ' '. Then the result is stored in @F. Hence $F[1] gives us the second column.

`-l` makes sure a newline is added to each line.

`-e` is used to specify the command we need to execute on each line which is print

```
$ perl -F, -ale 'print $F[1]' results.txt
33
32
34
31
30
35
28
3160
7450
1600
```

The above expands to the below program :

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -F, -ale 'print $F[1]' results.txt
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    chomp $_;
    our @F = split(/,/, $_, 0);
    print $F[1];
}
-e syntax OK
```